# EFA with target rotation

Tags: r, rotation, exploratory

Just trying to run an Exploratory Factor Analysis (EFA) with target rotation but are unable to do so with 100 variables for 15 factors. Our script is:

```
tcor<-cor(perma[c(1:100)],use = "pairwise",method = c("pearson"))
#we create a correlation matrix
ACCM<-fa(tcor,nfactors=15,n.obs = NA,rotate="none",fm="ml") 
gg<-ACCM$loadings[1:100,1:15]
# We create a factor loading matrix without rotation
taget<-target.rot(gg)

#Use Target rotation  but  get the error below  
Error in solve.default(U) : only square matrices can be inverted
```

Could anyone advise what does the error mean?
We are able to run this with 11 variables for 2 factors from the same data file.

Comment: Correct in what sense? We don't know what your data looks like, what your current results look like or your intended result! You need to be more specific in your question and provide some usable info. Help us help you!

Comment: I think EFA refers to Exploratory Factor Analysis.  Presumably there is a worked example in the psych pdf documentation.  Knowing the correct answer would help check the code.  Access to an example data set would also help.

Comment: Is there a worked example of what you want, maybe somewhere in Tucker and MacCallum's book?  http://www.unc.edu/~rcm/book/factor.pdf  Or elsewhere on the web that you could link to?